# Exits from Black's beach in San Diego

Tags: california, beaches, san-diego

If I go down to Black's beach [here](https://goo.gl/maps/FKbZ8vJuQEffyEAx8) and go south (towards Ellen Browning Scripps Memorial Pier) along the ocean, how far can I go and where can I exit? I walked 15-20 minutes in the direction mentioned above and I saw a car road that goes up from the beach. I wasn't able to find it on Google Maps. Where does it go? I didn't go further south along the ocean, but it was possible to go further (even though Google Maps showed that I was walking in the ocean). If I kept going, where would I be able to exit the beach?

Alternatively, if one goes north from the point in the link, are there any exits there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you head south you will be able to exit at [Torrey Pines City Beach](https://goo.gl/maps/QNXQPV3RDQazHuzF7), a path leads up to a suburb from which you can easily exit on to N Torrey Pines Road.

Further along south you can walk all the way to [La Jolla Shores](https://goo.gl/maps/YPkxjHnFQvLgbHWz5), a public beach with street access.

If you head north you will run into Torrey Pines State Reserve, from which there is [a trail](https://goo.gl/maps/vBGyG4zz2na3bD8Z8) that will lead you back up to the road. Going further north you will eventually hit the [entrance to the state reserve](https://goo.gl/maps/HzuJcBg6GvZzpDua9). Here the road runs right along the beach.

I can't remember how long it takes to walk, but it is at least a mile either way on sand, so I expect more than 20 minutes.

Comment: Do you know how low the tide should be to be able to walk to all those places?